# How to prevent a picture tag from stretching an image?

Tags: html, css

An image that gets loaded using a `<source>` tag gets stretched:

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h3>img tag (expected result):</h3>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    </div>
    
    <h3>picture tag:</h3>
    <div class="container">
      <picture>
        <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/184x184 184w,https://via.placeholder.com/100x100 100w" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
      </picture>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
      <picture>
        <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100 100w" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
      </picture>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I prevent this? I expect it to use its intrinsic size and only get stretched if I specify a width or `object-fit`. How can I achieve that?

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/michaelschufi/pen/GRZGJjw?editors=1100

Edit: Updated code.

Edit2: My goal is to give the user agent the choice which image it should take (based on the width descriptor / format), so it can optimize for bandwidth. Also, art direction is not what I am looking for.

Edit3:
Thank you for all the responses. As it turns out, [I cannot have a `srcset` without a `sizes` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-source-srcset) because of [image preloading](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/responsive-images-101-part-4-srcset-width-descriptors/). This means my syntax was incorrect.

Comment: use `display:block` to `img` ..

Comment: This is not working: https://codepen.io/michaelschufi/pen/dyMKozK?editors=1100

Comment: what is you expected result ? use `width:100%` ...

Comment: I want to _prevent_ the stretching. I expect it to behave the same way as without a picture tag.

Comment: try this ` <source media="(min-width:650px)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">` ..

Answer (score 0):

Your srcset value must be:

```
   <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
```

Not like this:

```
   <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100 100w" />
```

And look another srcset.

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h3>img tag:</h3>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    </div>
    
    <h3>picture tag:</h3>
    <div class="container">
      <picture>
        <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/184x184, https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
      </picture>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
      <picture>
        <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
      </picture>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? So far I only noticed that without the width descriptors the first image in the source set will be chosen and therefore preventing the browser from optimizing for bandwidth .

Comment: I hope [This](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/responsive-images-101-part-4-srcset-width-descriptors/) will help to you

Comment: Thank you! Your linked article and its next chapter explained why I have to specify the sizes attribute as well and why it is not possible to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

Use one image per source (in the `srcset` attribute) and use the `media` attribute. See the art direction section on this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images.

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h3>img tag:</h3>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    </div>
    
    <h3>picture tag:</h3>
    <div class="container">
      <picture>
        <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/184x184" media="(min-width: 400px)" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">
      </picture>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <picture>
        <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" media="(min-width: 400px)" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
      </picture>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/warhammered_cat/pen/MWyXwzm?editors=1100

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't need art direction, I think. My goal is to give the user agent the choice which image it should load. Like you would with `url 2x, url2 1.5x, url3 1x`. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something.